Alchemy Account Abstraction
I’m integrating the Account abstraction using alchemy AA and web3 auth. Using alchemy account kit guide.
I'm able to send a tx through alchemy AA on Sepolia.
However I couldn't interpret it.
The original tx is sending 0.000111 eth to
    const tx = {
        to: "0xcA33413f1B0A606D092cD7AB265624954816F82b", // w3a signer address
        amount
      }
      const receipt = await provider.sendTransaction(tx);


the tx receipt is
0x1911d3664abdf318cff0a7fd487c2846525868817f72ffa7c516f0d0ef66366a
I can see the tx details
https://jiffyscan.xyz/bundle/0x1911d3664abdf318cff0a7fd487c2846525868817f72ffa7c516f0d0ef66366a?network=sepolia&pageNo=0&pageSize=10
The signer is Web3Auth account 0xcA33413f1B0A606D092cD7AB265624954816F82b balance: 0.001
I expect it to decrease, but it doesn't.
Can you explain please?
Thank you
"use client";
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import Image from 'next/image'
import { createModularAccountAlchemyClient } from "@alchemy/aa-alchemy";
import { sepolia } from "@alchemy/aa-core";
import { createWeb3AuthSigner } from "./web3auth"
import { ethers } from 'ethers';

const ALCHEMY_API_KEY = ""
const ALCHEMY_GAS_MANAGER_POLICY_ID = ""
export default function Home() {
  const [provider, setProvider] = useState<any>();
  const [account, setAccount] = useState<any>();

  const chain = sepolia;

  useEffect(() => {
    async function init() {
      const w3aSigner = await createWeb3AuthSigner();
      const w3aSignerAddress = await w3aSigner.getAddress()
      const _p = await createModularAccountAlchemyClient({
        apiKey: ALCHEMY_API_KEY,
        chain,
        signer: w3aSigner,
        gasManagerConfig: {
          policyId: ALCHEMY_GAS_MANAGER_POLICY_ID,
        }
      });
  
      setProvider(_p);
      const balance = await _p.getBalance({
        address: _p.account.address,
      });
      console.log(`Alchemy Account address ${_p.account.address} balance: ${ethers.utils.formatEther(balance)}`);

      const w3aSignerBalance = await _p.getBalance({
        address: w3aSignerAddress,
      });
      console.log(`w3a signer address: ${w3aSignerAddress} balance: ${ethers.utils.formatEther(w3aSignerBalance)}`);
      
    }

    init();

  }, []);

  const sendTx = async () => {
    try {
      const amount = ethers.utils.parseEther("0.000111");
      const tx = {
        to: "0xcA33413f1B0A606D092cD7AB265624954816F82b", // w3a signer address
        amount
      }
      const receipt = await provider.sendTransaction(tx);
      console.log("Receipt", receipt);
      
    } catch (error) {
      
    }
  }

  return (
    <main className="flex flex-row">
      <h1>Alchemy Auth</h1>
      <button 
        onClick={sendTx}
        className="border-2 border-red-500 px-2">Send Tx</button>
    </main>
  )
}


